# Xamarin.Froms Frame BackgroudColor change not showing

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Ihave this scenario: A ListView and every Cell is a frame. When showing the list all frames backgroudcolor is white when i click on frame i want the color to change in  blie. I change the color but not refreshing. This is my code:
In xaml page

```
   <pages:PopupPage.Resources>
        <local1:ChangeFrameBackgroudColor x:Key="ChangeFrameBackgroudColor" />
    </ResourceDictionary>-->
    </pages:PopupPage.Resources>
  <ListView x:Name="IzberiFirmaListView" HasUnevenRows="True"  ItemsSource="{Binding KorisnikFirmi}" SelectedItem="{Binding IzbranaFirmaId } " Header="{Binding}" ItemTapped="IzberiFirmaListView_ItemTapped">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <local:ExtendedViewCell SelectedBackgroundColor="#2188ff"  >

                            <StackLayout  Padding="20, 10"  >
                                <Frame x:Name="frameLabel" BorderColor="#2188ff" BackgroundColor="{Binding IsActive, Converter={StaticResource ChangeFrameBackgroudColor}}">
                                    <Label  FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="18" TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding Naziv}" ></Label>
                                </Frame>
                            </StackLayout>

                        </local:ExtendedViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentView BackgroundColor="#006BE6" >
                            <Label Margin="10" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Text="ОДБЕРЕТЕ ФИРМА"  TextColor="White" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                        </ContentView>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

In xaml.cs Page:

```
        private void IzberiFirmaListView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            var vm = BindingContext as OdberiFirmaPopupViewModel;
            var firm = e.Item as SysDashFirma;
            vm.ChangeColorOnItemSelected(firm);


        }
```

In viewModel

```
    public List<SysDashFirma> KorisnikFirmi
        {
            get { return korisnikFirmi; }
            set
            {
                if (korisnikFirmi != value)
                {
                    korisnikFirmi = value;

                    SetProperty(ref korisnikFirmi, value);
                    OnPropertyChanged("KorisnikFirmi");

                }
            }
        }
  public void ChangeColorOnItemSelected(SysDashFirma firm)
        {
            if (_oldFirmSelected == firm)
            {
                //firm.BackColor = "#2188ff";
                firm.IsActive = true;
                UpdateSelectedFirmItemColor(firm);
            }
            else
            {
                if(_oldFirmSelected != null)
                {
                    //_oldFirmSelected.BackColor = "#f5f5f5";
                    _oldFirmSelected.IsActive = false;
                    UpdateSelectedFirmItemColor(_oldFirmSelected);
                }
                // firm.BackColor = "#2188ff";
                firm.IsActive = true;
                UpdateSelectedFirmItemColor(firm);
            }


            _oldFirmSelected = firm;
        }

        private void UpdateSelectedFirmItemColor(SysDashFirma firm)
        {
            var index = KorisnikFirmi.IndexOf(firm);
            KorisnikFirmi.Remove(firm);
            KorisnikFirmi.Insert(index,firm);
        }
```

Changes are made in the list ,flag is changed, probably cant refresh the bidning context to converter read all from start.

Comment: I have a few doubts,
Do you use OnPropertyChanged for The IsActive property?
Is the converter code trigger while to change the IsActive property?(Use break points to check)

Comment: I have IsActive  in  SysDashFirma object

Comment: i have Inotify on that list

Comment: Converter is not trigger when i change the value of the Selected Firm

Comment: You have INotify on the List, but you change the IsActive property of the `SysDashFirma` object. The `IsActive` change is not notified to your UI. Please try adding OnPropertyChanged to the `IsActive` Property. Am I missing something?

Comment: Moreover you are adding and removing from the List which will not be visible in the UI you will need to use `ObservableCollection` instead of the `List`

Comment: I changed it to ObservableCollection. Now change the color on the selected Frame, but the old one is desapiring its not showing

Comment: In the frame {Binding Naziv} is not showing just on _oldFirm

Comment: The old one is disappearing because you are removing it from the collection Why is it being removed from the collection?. Did adding OnPropertyChanged solve the BackgroundColor issue?

Comment: Yes it showing now the backgroud when i select. But in old  one is lost  the name of the firm

Comment: Debug by setting a breakpoint in the Naziv property, Check for any code setting an Empty string or null to the property

Comment: I really dont know what is the problem

Comment: I have added a answer please do check if it helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use OnPropertyChanged for the IsActive property to notify the UI about its change.

```cs
public class Firm : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name = "Unknown";

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool isActive;

    public bool IsActive
    {
        get
        {
            return isActive;
        }
        set
        {
            isActive = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

I would suggest changing the `IsActive` property alone as removing and adding the item is not necessary.

```cs
<ListView
    ItemTapped="ListView_ItemTapped"
    ItemsSource="{Binding FirmCollection}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Frame
                    Padding="2"
                    BackgroundColor="{Binding IsActive, Converter={StaticResource converterTest}}">
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </Frame>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**ViewModel**

```cs
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

....
....

    private Firm oldSelectedFirm;

    public Firm OldSelectedFirm
    {
        get
        {
            return oldSelectedFirm;
        }
        set
        {
            oldSelectedFirm = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

...
...

}
```

**Xaml.cs**

```cs
void ListView_ItemTapped(System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    var tappedFirm = (e.Item as Firm);
    var vm = (BindingContext as ViewModel);
    if (vm.OldSelectedFirm != null)
        vm.OldSelectedFirm.IsActive = false;

    tappedFirm.IsActive = true;
    vm.OldSelectedFirm = tappedFirm;
}
```

Comment: Just need you select one , when u want to select another the old one backgroud need to be white again

Comment: Maybe with SelectMode single?

Comment: I have changed (Set IsActive to false to oldFirm and added a Property as OldFirm in the ViewModel) as you had asked please check now. Selection Color can not be changed in a ListView, there is no API for that.

Comment: YEsss its working. added on property changed in IsActivy

Comment: But i have added onPropertyChanged on all ObservableCollection of Firms why dont change with that?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. Do you meant to say to change the IsActive with the ObservableCollection's OnPropertyChanged. If you want to change the color of a single item, ObservableCollection's PropertyChanged doesn't help

Comment: In my class SysDashFirm on IsActive i added:
  public bool IsActive
        {
            get
            {
                return isActive;
            }
            set
            {
                isActive = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

Comment: Previously was just public bool IsActive { get; set; } with this dont work